# Send files from multi-term to buffer

Tags: multi-term

I'm currently using emacs24 and multi-term, my frame is split in two windows, top for buffers and the bottom terminals.

When I need to open a new file I have to go to buffers and C-x C-f, I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid this and instead send files from current terminal path to buffers.

EDIT:

What I want to do is be able to open a file from the current pwd in multi-term and send it to the top window, avoiding to create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

If you press `C-x 4 f`, it runs `#'find-file-other-window`, which is like `C-x C-f` in that it prompts for and opens a file, but instead of opening the file in the current window, opens it in another one.

If you have two windows open (as in your description), it'll use the other one. It will move point into the newly opened file. If you don't want that to happen, you could make an elisp function to open a file in the other window, then move back to your initial window.

Comment: This certanly helps, but please read edits.

Comment: @deadPoet What about your question isn't answered? It seems to work fine for me, albeit with the usual "Use `C-c` instead of `C-x` inherent to term-mode.

Comment: well, I have two windows, your solution creates me another one, but I want to open the file in the existing window that does not contain multi-term.